# Clojure type hints syntax

Tags: types, clojure

In the book "Programming Clojure" (Halloway, S., (2009). Programming Clojure. Raleigh, NC: Pragmatic Bookshelf.) he shows type hints using the syntax

```
(defn describe-class [#^Class c]
  ...)
```

while on the [Clojure Website](http://clojure.org/java_interop), the type hints are shown without the `#` reader macro:

```
(defn len2 [^String x]
  ...)
```

Which is correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both are, but in different versions of Clojure: beginning with the 1.2 release, `#^` syntax for reader metadata (in particular, type hints) is deprecated and `^` is to be used instead. Note that `#^` still *works* in 1.2; also note that `^foo` was shorthand for `(meta foo)` prior to 1.2, so you *have* to use the old notation if you use an older release.

Comment: ł: Thanks. I did not realize that the syntax had changed.