# What is the difference between `#^` type hint and `^` type hint?

Tags: clojure

I have seen type hints in both styles, for example, `clojure-contrib.server-socket` writes:

```
(.close #^ServerSocket (:server-socket server))
```

And Clojure's java-interop document uses only `^` to do type hinting.

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#^` syntax is deprecated in favor of the `^` syntax. See [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245540/clojure-type-hints-syntax).