# Meta reader literals: ^ vs. #^

Tags: clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clojure type hints syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245540/clojure-type-hints-syntax)

At times I read `^{:meta :data} some-form`, and at others, `#^{:meta :data} some-form`, with a trailing hash character. What is the difference between both?

There's no related entry in [clojure.org/reader](http://clojure.org/reader).

Comment: How was I supposed to find the previous identical question if it had a pretty much unrelated title? Saddening how certain SO users can spend their time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference at the moment. https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L82 - if you can read java, take a look there. ^ is getting processed by MetaReader and # by DispatchReader which (in case of #^) does call MetaReader. Why? As I remember, in early days of clojure ^ was used for something else (meta, but I might be wrong). I'd suggest to stick to ^ at the moment, it's more... preferred... these days.

Comment: Thanks for including the source! Using chars for Java array access is neat.

Answer (score 2):

`#^` is the old reader macro-character for accesssing meta-data.

It is now deprecated in favor of `^`.

The following page officially lists `^` as the reader macro-character for metadata: http://clojure.org/reader